# Cannot get custom collision event to fire c++ UE5

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I've followed a couple of tutorials on creating custom collision events, but mine never triggers. I'm getting desperate! I've almost literally copied an existing working UE4 project, but cannot get the collision event to fire. Please help!

My header:

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Components/BoxComponent.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "Kismet/GameplayStatics.h"
#include "StarWarsDrone.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class STARWARSTRAINING_UE5_API AStarWarsDrone : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
        AActor* Enemy;
    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = Collision, meta = (AllowPrivateAccess = "true"))
        class UBoxComponent* CollisionBox;


public: 
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    AStarWarsDrone();

    UFUNCTION()
    void OnAttackHit(UPrimitiveComponent* HitComponent, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, FVector NormalImpulse, const FHitResult& Hit);

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

};
```

my .cpp:

```
#include "StarWarsDrone.h"

AStarWarsDrone::AStarWarsDrone()
{
    // Set this actor to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    CollisionBox = CreateDefaultSubobject<UBoxComponent>(TEXT("CollisionBox"));
    CollisionBox->SetupAttachment(RootComponent);
    CollisionBox->SetCollisionProfileName("NoCollision");
    CollisionBox->SetNotifyRigidBodyCollision(false);
    CollisionBox->SetHiddenInGame(false);

}

void AStarWarsDrone::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    // attach collision components to sockets based on transformations definitions
    const FAttachmentTransformRules AttachmentRules(EAttachmentRule::SnapToTarget, EAttachmentRule::SnapToTarget, EAttachmentRule::KeepWorld, false);

    CollisionBox->AttachToComponent(RootComponent, AttachmentRules, "SphereCollisionSocket");
    CollisionBox->OnComponentHit.AddDynamic(this, &AStarWarsDrone::OnAttackHit);

}

void AStarWarsDrone::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);
}

void AStarWarsDrone::OnAttackHit(UPrimitiveComponent* HitComponent, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, FVector NormalImpulse, const FHitResult& Hit)
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("OUCH"));
}
```

In editor, CollisionBox has "simulation generates hit events" set to True.
Any tips as to why this never triggers? Thanks!

Comment: I know nothing about ue, but  line 10 of the second file stands out to me.

Comment: Do you have "Simulate generate hit events" checked for the instance? Your delegate will not fire unless you have that.

Comment: You can set "Simulate generate hit events" to true from C++ as well by calling this function (yes the naming of the booleans are different but they are the same. )
 https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/UPrimitiveComponent/SetNotifyRigidBodyCollision/

Comment: I do:
"In editor, CollisionBox has "simulation generates hit events" set to True".

In any case, I'm not sure that's even relevant, as I think that control whether this object generates hit events for the thing it's hitting, not the other way round...

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).